# Dyntopo ruptured and torn topology

Tags: sculpting

I have these ruptured holes everywhere in my sculpt (picture is after smoothing to really emphasize issue, the are very very small otherwise).

[image]

I've tried filling them with faces, removing double vertexes and re-sculpting these areas but they keep popping up in a myriad of places, causing distorted baking to low poly version:

[image]

It looks like a double sided mesh from edit mode, but I can't figure out how it happened or how I would go about to fix it. This is roughly 5 hours of work, I really don't want to lose it.

[image]

Comment: Check that your normals are consistent. In edit mode press Ctrl+N

Comment: Turns out I have a doubled mesh (in some parts) with opposite normals. I've tried recalculating them but it doesn't work; manually would take hours on hours.

Any ideas?

Comment: In edit mode select all of your mesh (A) and do "remove doubles" Then do Ctrl+A

Comment: I already did this, as stated in my original post. The vertexes aren't identical.

Comment: Can you provide a part of the problem mesh at [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ? The problem could be in somehow duplicating the mesh which was later partially intersecting with the original one; removing doubles then partially connected them with each other.